# Save and load operations in a Portlet - jsp file cannot find the file

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I am generating .svg files in a Liferay portlet na saving them in a svg folder which is located on a server (JBoss AS). These files are generated and saved in a .java class, something like this:

```
private void saveSVG(Document doc, String fileName) {
    // save svg to file
    try {
        File file = new File("svg/" + fileName + ".svg"); // make file
        PrintWriter writer;
        writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)); // write and
                                                                // save file
        DOMUtilities.writeDocument(doc, writer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("File path: " + file.getPath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file is saved in server/bin/svg directory. But when I try to access the file in my .jsp page, it cannot seem to find the file (its probably looking in another directory). How can I tell it, where the desired file is? I could use absolute path, store it somewhere and pass it to the .jsp page, but that doesnt seem like very elegant solution.

```
<object data="svg/topBar.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Or how can I save the file to a relative path where the .jsp page will find it using the upper code?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: "topBar.svg" is obviously the fileName I am using in this example

Comment: Careful: If you save the files in a location directly readable from the web, you're opening up yourself for multiple issues: When you deploy an update to your application, chances are that you're loosing the files stored within that app. It's not portable throughout application servers (might break with the next version). Further, if your webapp directory is writeable to the web application and you're not extra careful, you open yourself up to remote code execution, e.g. somebody uploading a jsp file and accessing it - executed serverside.

Comment: @OlafKock The files should be saved in a a .war directory where the portlet is (on the server) and will be used only once after they are created - I dont think that this is the issue, but I am not an expert on this...

Comment: A better solution with portlets would be to use a serveResourceURL to provide your SVG and write it directly to the outputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using new File() in the Java code, create the file in a location which is relative to the location of the command line when you started your JBoss while the path in the JSP is relative to your webapp context.

Not sure but I think you can try:

`File file = new File(getPortletContext().getRealPath("svg/topBar.svg"))`